# Characters vanish from string upon function end

Tags: ruby, string

I'm writing a program to generate words for a language. Here's my code:

```
def correct(list)
    unless @vowel
        filter_consonants(list)
        similarity_avoidance(list)
    end
    puts "Corrected list: " + list
    return list
end

def similarity_avoidance(list)
    puts list.size
    sublist = ""
    subsublist = ""
    list.each_char do |character|
        sublist += character if similarity_exists?(character, @root)
    end
    sublist.each_char do |character|
        subsublist += character if @root.include?(character)
    end
    sublist.each_char do |character|
        sublist.delete!(character) if subsublist.include?(character)
    end
    sublist += subsublist
    list.each_char do |character|
        list.delete!(character) if sublist.include?(character)
    end
    list += sublist
    puts "Corrected for similarity: " + list
end
```

When a string of characters is altered by a function, some of the characters in the string vanish. I do not know what I'm doing wrong or whether I am. Does anyone know anything?

Comment: It would help if you tell us with what input you get what results and also include `similarity_exists?`.

Comment: Explain how it is used, with sample input and output.

Comment: Oh; I managed to get it working already. Incidentally, though, the program is mostly automatic, and I mainly noticed the eating-characters issue because my program started crashing. And the 'similarity_exists?' function isn't all that relevant; it just checks to see if there are similar consonants in the root already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the value of the string object that was passed into the function as the parameter `list`. What you are doing is assigning a different string object to `list` inside the body of the function. `list` is not an object, it is a reference to one object or another -- and the `list` in the function's parameter list is a different reference than the `list` defined outside the function.  It would be helpful to rename the parameter, to clarify matters.

What you need to do is get that inside value to the outside. The mechanism for doing that in a function is the return statement.

Try returning the new value of (inside) `list` from the function, and assign the functions return value to the outside `list` when you call the function.

That same logic applies to both of the functions where you are trying to alter the value of `list`. You'll need to return `list` at the end of `filter_consonants` too.

```
def correct(list)
    unless @vowel
        list = filter_consonants(list)
        list = similarity_avoidance(list)
    end
    puts "Corrected list: " + list
    return list
end

def similarity_avoidance(list)
    puts list.size
    sublist = ""
    subsublist = ""
    list.each_char do |character|
        sublist += character if similarity_exists?(character, @root)
    end
    sublist.each_char do |character|
        subsublist += character if @root.include?(character)
    end
    sublist.each_char do |character|
        sublist.delete!(character) if subsublist.include?(character)
    end
    sublist += subsublist
    list.each_char do |character|
        list.delete!(character) if sublist.include?(character)
    end
    list += sublist
    puts "Corrected for similarity: " + list
    return list
end
```